# htmlspecialchars in search

Tags: 7, search

When I'm searching my site, I get this error:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars(): Invalid multibyte sequence in argument in check_plain() (line 1476 of /var/www/includes/bootstrap.inc).

What does it mean and how can I correct it?

EDIT:
The problem disappeared after migrating to webhosting server, so the problem should be something in settings in my local computer.

Comment: WHat version of Drupal and what version of PHP?

Comment: What charset are you using, and have you looked at headers to see if everything is working as expected, and that everything is being done with a consistent charset?

Comment: @MPD PHP 5.3.2, Drupal 7

Comment: @MPD Where can I see what charset I'm using and look at the headers?

Comment: Use Firefox.  You should see then in Right-Click, Page Info or use the Live HTTP Headers plugin to watch the whole transfer, including redirects.

Comment: @MPD in Page Info there is encoding UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the search module. It does not handle multibyte characters correctly. Watch this thread: http://drupal.org/node/987472
Fixing the search module fixed the problem for me. However wait for an authorized patch.

Your webhoster doesn't show the error not because it is not there, but because they have a better production settings. The error can be easily suppressed using PHP settings.

Comment: OK I'll wait for authorized patch and believe it's the bug and accept your answer (if somebody won't persuade us that the problem is elsewhere)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding some instrumentation by replacing the check_plain function with this version:

```
function check_plain($text) {
  $plain = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  if (empty($plain) && !empty($text)) {
    dpm($text);
    ddebug_backtrace();
  }
}
```

You will need to have the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module enabled.  The next time the error is triggered, the offending text will be displayed along with a backtrace that shows what function triggered the error.  With that info, you can search your code and database for the offending text and remove it.

Comment: Can I log this information to some file without installing `devel` module?

Comment: you can replace the debug statements with native PHP:error_log($text, 3, '/tmp/text.log');
error_log(var_dump(debug_backtrace()), 3, '/tmp/trace.log'); 
  
the devel output is much easier to understand, though.

Comment: I tried it but with this replacement the web does not work. It lost all styles I can't see many things and I can't click on nothing (it doesn't react).

Comment: The problem disappeared after migrating to webhosting server, so the problem should be something in settings in my local computer.

Answer (score 1):

This has occured to me because I had left some Unicode (é, ó...) in a template file or a module, be sure to check this. Generally you need to use the `t()` function and then translate your string in the translate interface `admin/build/translate`.
If you can't do this, you can use `utf8_encode('é')` but that's not very pretty.

Comment: I'm using only english characters in coding.

Comment: May be you are passing an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess here, but I suspect something isn't UTF-8 clean.

[check_plain](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) is hardcoded for UTF-8.  I suspect that you are some part of your transfer is in ISO-8859-1.

Watch the transfer with Live HTTP Headers.  If you see anything other than UTF-8 in requests or responses, then you need to tweak some non-Drupal settings.

Comment: Live HTTP Headers shows `Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
` but I have no idea what to change in Drupal settings.